# Issue with getting data from api in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get data from the Google custom search json api for use for my extension. However, whenever I try to send the fetch request below it throws an error that I do not know how to fix.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I have tried to do the same request in my browser and it seems to work fine.

I tried to use an XMLHttp request instead which also did not work. I also tried to use the fetch api to get data from other api's which worked. I also tried to alter permissions and added https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1 to the permissions in the manifest.json.

```
   fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=skeet&cx=mysearchid&key=my_api_key')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
    });
```

Comment: When you get the SyntaxError, what is the value of `myJson`, if you `console.log(myJson)` before trying to `JSON.stringify` it?

Comment: The error occurs at return response.json();. If I console.log before that it returns a response object with a status code of 200.

Comment: The very first thing to do is to verify the actual response instead of guessing. Open devtools, the network panel, and inspect the body of the response. Also note, content scripts can't fetch cross-origin URLs in modern Chrome, you need a background script, see the [CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).